# Faithful actions of finite groups on topological spaces

Tags: group-actions, gn.general-topology, dg.differential-geometry

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group acting faithfully on a topological space $X$. In the smooth setting, one can deduce that for each $x$ in $M$, the induced map $$G_x \to Diff_x\left(M\right)$$ from the isotropy group of $x$ to the group of germs of locally defined diffeomorphisms is a monomorphism. **Does this result hold true in the topological setting**? (Replacing diffeomorphisms with homeomorphisms)

In the smooth setting, the result follows from the following standard lemma:

**Lemma:** *Let $M$ be a manifold and $G$ a finite subgroup of $\mathit{Diff}\left(M\right)$. Then for any smooth map $f:V \to M$ defined on a non-empty open connected submanifold of $M,$ such that $f\left(x\right) \in G \cdot x$ for all $x,$ there exists a unique element $g \in G$ such that $f=g|_V.$ *

I'm guessing the answer is NO  for general topological spaces. However, a counter-example would be nice.

Comment: The answer is no.  Consider your space to be a wedge of a bunch of circles -- and don't use common wedge points.  Then an involution can fix a neighbourhood of a point and still flip some of the circle wedge summands. 

Comment: I suspect the answer is yes for connected topological manifolds but I don't have an argument off the top of my head.  These kinds of questions were investigated in the 60's as far as I know.  

Comment: @Ryan: Thanks. I'm glad to see that there is such a simple counter-example.

Comment: maybe Ryan or David can repost this as an answer and close the question ?